# Add UIView to UIWindow causes memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, addsubview

I have a view like this:

```
@interface MyView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* subView;

@end

@implementation MyView

#pragma mark - init && dealloc

-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){        
        [self setupSubView];
        [self setupAutoLayoutSubView];        
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - setup

-(void)setupSubView
{
    _subView = [UIView newAutoLayoutView];
    [self addSubview:_subView];
}

-(void)setupAutoLayoutSubView
{
    // autolayout: to centralize the subView
    // if you don't use PureLayout, you can use the traditional way
    [_subView autoCenterInSuperview];
}

@end
```

When I add this view into Window, the reference counting on this view will  be increased to 3.

```
MyView* v = [[MyView alloc] init];
NSLog(@"reference counting = %ld",CFGetRetainCount((CFTypeRef)v)); //- 1

UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[window addSubView:v];

NSLog(@"reference counting = %ld",CFGetRetainCount((CFTypeRef)v)); //- 3 INCORRECT
```

The strange thing is if I comment the "**autolayout**" part from method: "**setupAutoLayoutSubView**", the reference counting is correct ( = 2 )

or if I add my view to a normal view, the reference counting is correct as well

```
MyView* v = [[MyView alloc] init];
NSLog(@"reference counting = %ld",CFGetRetainCount((CFTypeRef)v)); //- 1

UIView* normalView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[normalView addSubView:v];

NSLog(@"reference counting = %ld",CFGetRetainCount((CFTypeRef)v)); //- 2 : CORRECT
```

Comment: What is actually indicating a leak?  (If it adds 2 at one point and subtracts 2 later, that should be a non-problem.)  If you need to know, try running Instruments with the Allocations (or Leaks) tool.  It should let you trace the retain/release history of an object.

Comment: Why does it add 2 at one point? The thing is later when I try to remove "MyView" from Window, the view is still there, because the view has as you said "2 references" at one point.